# How to permanently set some path in @INC

Tags: perl

I want to set a path in @INC, as script is failing to locate perl module. Requirement is that , i cannot include the module path in the script directly.
So , i am thinking to add module path directly in @INC. Is there a way i can do that.

I have tried to edit ~/.bash_profile , ~/.bashrc as well. But its not adding the path in @INC.

Answer (score 3):

There are various ways:

- call as `perl -Ipath script.pl`
- call as `PERL5OPT=path script.pl`
- globally set `export PERL5OPT=path` in `.profile` or `PERL5OPT=path` in `.pam_environment` (affects other scripts too)

Answer (score 1):

If you've modified `~/.bashrc` and it hasn't added it to your environment, then you are probably adding it to your `PATH`. The best way to do this is to use the `PERL5LIB` environment variable.

If you want to do this at the start of each shell session no matter what is going on, add the following line to `~/.bashrc` (assuming that the shell is bash) and the source the script or start a new shell session.

```
export PERL5LIB=/path/to/module
```

If you want to do it only in that script, add the following line after the shebang:

```
use lib '/path/to/module';
```

If you just want to do it as fast as possible, run the script with `perl -I`

```
perl -I /path/to/module script.pl
```

All of these methods will prepend the directory containing the module to `@INC`

Answer (score 0):

I found the simple soultion of it.

push(@INC,/path) or unshift(@INC,'/path)

Second method : use lib "/path" in file itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first line of calling .pl, e.g.:

```
use lib ".";
```